# How to unit test angularjs controller with $location service

Tags: unit-testing, angularjs

I am trying to create a simple unit test that tests my show function.

I get the following error:

```
TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'show'
```

It seems like `$rootScope` isn't the scope of the controller?

Here's my controller:

```
function OpponentsCtrl($scope, $location) {
    $scope.show = function(url) {
        $location.path(url);
    }
}
OpponentsCtrl.$inject = ['$scope', '$location'];
```

Here's my controller unit test:

```
describe('OpponentsCtrl', function() {
    beforeEach(module(function($provide) {
        $provide.factory('OpponentsCtrl', function($location){
            // whatever it does...
        });
    }));

    it('should change location when setting it via show function', inject(function($location, $rootScope, OpponentsCtrl) {
        $location.path('/new/path');
        $rootScope.$apply();
        expect($location.path()).toBe('/new/path');

        $rootScope.show('/test');
        expect($location.path()).toBe('/test');
    }));
});
```

Comment: "Unit test" is two words, just wanted to point it out. Glad you found a solution.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Why don't you simply use a spyOn function?

```
describe('OpponentsCtrl', function() {

    var location;

    beforeEach(module(function($provide) {
        $provide.factory('OpponentsCtrl', function($location){
            location = $location;
        });
    }));

    it('should change location when setting it via show function', inject(function() {    
        spyOn(location, 'path');    
        expect(location.path).toHaveBeenCalledWith('/new/path');
    }));
});
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Why do you have the inject in the test if you aren't using it? I assume this is just left over from when you did?

Comment: @Katana24, I have removed the inject. Please peer review the changes if you like.

Answer (score 65):

This is how my test ended up working.

```
describe('OpponentsCtrl', function() {
    var scope, rootScope, ctrl, location;

    beforeEach(inject(function($location, $rootScope, $controller) {
        location = $location;
        rootScope = $rootScope;
        scope = $rootScope.$new();
        ctrl = $controller(OpponentsCtrl, {$scope: scope});
    }));

    it('should change location when setting it via show function', function() {
        location.path('/new/path');
        rootScope.$apply();
        expect(location.path()).toBe('/new/path');

        // test whatever the service should do...
        scope.show('/test');
        expect(location.path()).toBe('/test');

    });
});
```

Comment: By the way, you can feel free to accept your own answer.  It looks like, to date, it has helped 20 people :-).

Comment: don't you have to mock $httpBackend? i get "Error: Unexpected request: GET No more request expected". I need to mock it.

Comment: I second mgilson -- accept this one as the correct answer. After a thorough search, this is what made it work for me! Lots of thanks!

Comment: You really should accept as the correct answer, it helped me a lot.

Answer (score 3):

I prefer to mock location and services as then it's a unit (not integration) test:

```
'use strict';
describe('flightController', function () {
  var scope;
  var searchService;
  var location;

  beforeEach(module('app'));
  beforeEach(inject(function ($controller, $rootScope) {
    scope = $rootScope.$new();
    mockSearchService();
    mockLocation();
    createController($controller);
  }));

  it('changes location to month page', function () {
    searchService.flightToUrl.and.returnValue('Spain/Ukraine/December/1');
    scope.showMonth();
    expect(location.url).toHaveBeenCalledWith('search/month/Spain/Ukraine/December/1');
  });

  function mockSearchService() {
    searchService = jasmine.createSpyObj('searchService', ['flightToUrl']);
  }

  function mockLocation() {
    location = jasmine.createSpyObj('location', ['url']);
  }

  function createController($controller) {
    $controller('flightController', {
      $scope: scope,
      searchService: searchService,
      $location: location
    });
  }
});
```

Cheers